# Gulp-notify not showing toast notification

Tags: gulp, toast, gulp-notify

I have a custom error handler that's supposed to show a notification with `gulp-notify` and then log it in the console.

```
module.exports = function () {
    return plumber(function (err) {
        notify({
            title: 'Gulp Build Error',
            message: 'Check the Task Runner or console for more details.'
        }).write(err);

        gutil.log(err);
        this.emit('end');
    });
};
```

I'm inclined to believe it's set up properly, because it's successfully printing this in the console (followed by the error details):

```
[15:35:04] gulp-notify: [Gulp Build Error] Check the Task Runner or console for more details.
```

However, no toast notification is being displayed. Oddly enough, this exact configuration was displaying it a few weeks ago. Does anyone see any red flags in the way this is configured or know of anything that may be preventing the toast notification from popping up? I'm on Windows 8.1, and SnoreToast is set to show notifications in Notifications Settings.

Thanks.

**Update:** This appears to be a Windows 8.1 issue. I ran this on a Windows 10 machine and the notification showed up.